# How to compare string values of CharSequence[]?

Tags: java, android, charsequence

I have the following `CharSequence` defined:

```
final CharSequence[] videoQualities = {"any", "medium", "high", "hd"};
```

I am getting two `string` values: `availableQuality` and `requestedQuality`. Both can contain values from the `CharSequence` above only.

How can I check if `availableQuality` more or equal to `requestedQuality`?

Comment: how can string be compared as more or less with one another? Are you talking about their positions?

Comment: What do you mean by this "How can I check if availableQuality more or equal to requestedQuality?" Does medium > any etc?

Comment: @Umair Ashraf, @Java Drinker, yes, this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an ArrayList instead of CharSequence[]. You can then use ArrayList.indexOf() to return a numeric index that you can use to compare position in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Enum to rescue.

define videoQualities as enum

public enum VideoQualities {
    any, medium, high, hd
}

VideoQualities availableQuality;
VideoQualities requestedQuality;

if (availableQuality.ordinal() >= requestedQuality.ordinal()) {
....
}

Comment: I thought this originally but the OP's values are strings not integers.

Comment: what do you mean by OP ? you can always convert String into enum using valueOf method: VideoQualities hd = VideoQualities.valueOf("hd")

Comment: OP = 'Original post' or 'original poster' (the question or person who asked the question). By the way, I didn't think of using enum that way, thanks for teaching me something (+1).