# How to compare a CharSequence to a String - Android

Tags: java, android, string, charsequence

I have a class that places a text into an arrayList. Then it makes all the variables into CharSequences, when I try to compare the variables to a String such as == "test"; it doesn't work here is my code that I use to get the variables

```
class Item {
            String descs;

            public Item (String descs){

                 this.descs = descs;

                 }


            public CharSequence getDescs() {
                return descs;
            }
        }
```

This is the code that compares it to the String

```
 if(p.getDescs().toString() == "trash"){

          descsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }

          else{
              descsView.setText(p.getDescs());

                            }
```

I know for a fact that p.getDescs() is equal to trash because when it sets the text for descsView it is set to trash. SO why doesn't the first if statement work?

Comment: I am reopening this question because the [supposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) does not deal `CharSequence`. There are valid cases when `.equals` could return false not because the content is different, but because one is a `String` and the other is a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings

```
     if(p.getDescs().toString().equals("trash"))
```

Also check this

[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Answer (score 16):

## Intro

A `CharSequence` is a general type that includes other types like `String`, `StringBuilder`, `SpannableString`, and others. If you are comparing two strings you can just use `.equals` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)). But if you are comparing a `String` to a `CharSequence`, you have to decide what it is you want to compare, since you might be comparing a `String` to a `StringBuilder` or a `SpannableString` or something else.

## Compare content only

If you only want to compare the content (ie, text) of a `String` to the content of the `CharSequence`, but you don't care about the type, then you can use `String.contentEquals()`.

```
String myString = "hello";
CharSequence myCharSequence = new StringBuilder("hello");

boolean areEqual = myString.contentEquals(myCharSequence); // true
```

## Compare content and type

If you also want to make sure the types are the same in addition to the content, then use `String.equals()`.

```
String myString = "hello";
CharSequence myCharSequence = new StringBuilder("hello");

boolean areEqual = myString.equals(myCharSequence); // false
```

Here it is again with the same types.

```
String myString = "hello";
CharSequence myCharSequence = "hello"; // String

boolean areEqual = myString.equals(myCharSequence); // true
```

## See also

- [CharSequence VS String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049228/charsequence-vs-string-in-java/47222086#47222086)
- [Android Spanned, SpannedString, Spannable, SpannableString and CharSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546955/android-spanned-spannedstring-spannable-spannablestring-and-charsequence/41935087#41935087)
- [Difference between String#equals and String#contentEquals methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476600/difference-between-stringequals-and-stringcontentequals-methods)

Comment: I wasn’t aware of `contentEquals()` before. It’s useful here. Plus one.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `equals()` method for String comparison...

```
if(p.getDescs().toString().equals("trash")){
    descsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
else{
    descsView.setText(p.getDescs());
    }
```

Refer to [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If descs is your CharSequence variable:

```
descs.toString().equals("SomeString");
```

Answer (score 1):

The Best method should be like thi s

```
if("trash".equals(p.getDescs()){
    descsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
else{
    descsView.setText(p.getDescs());
    }
```

Alternatively if comparison is not case sensitive then

```
 if("trash".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getDescs()){
        descsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    else{
        descsView.setText(p.getDescs());
        }
```

The function

```
 <String>.equalus(Object)
```

Compare any string varialbe to value of Object varialble

**Note:** Because the value of `p.getDescs()` could be null

so using

```
if(p.getDescs().toString().equals("trash")){
    descsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
else{
    descsView.setText(p.getDescs());
    }
```

### may through **error** on Runtime

following links may help

[How to compare string values of CharSequence[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782638/how-to-compare-string-values-of-charsequence?rq=1)

[CharSequence vs String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049228/charsequence-vs-string-in-java?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer

```
if(p.getDescs().toString().equals("trash"))
```

can be simplified to

```
if("trash".contentEquals(p.getDescs()))
```

Suragch's "Intro" answer gives the details. This is the way to directly compare a CharSequence to a String, which is what the OP asked for.